# Strange behavior of type-attribute in inputs in Chrome, FF, IE & Opera

Tags: html

I found nothing in the HTML Spec about how a browser (Google Chrome, FF, IE & Opera all in latest version) has to behave if there is an onclick handler on an input with a wrong type, so i'm asking you, experts :)

I used the following html and imagined the browser gave me some kind of error (maybe just in the developer console log), but it just reloads the whole page!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <button type="button color" onclick="document.getElementById('magic').innerHTML='clicked broken button'">Broken Button</button>
        <button type="button"       onclick="document.getElementById('magic').innerHTML='clicked button'"       >Button</button>
    </form>
    <p id="magic"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the first button has a wrong type, whereas the second button has a correct type. Both buttons have nearly the same onclick-handler, the only difference is the text of the paragraph, that is changed.

When you click on the first button, the paragraph's text is changed and the whole page reloads, which results in an empty paragraph. When you click on the second button, everything acts as expected and the paragraph's text is just changed - without a reload.

So, can you tell me why reloading the whole page is the default behavior in all 4 major browsers. Shouldn't a browser make a hint about a miss-typed button (maybe by printing an error message in the developer console log). For me this is very confusing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for the `type` attribute of a [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) element is `submit`. This means that when such an element is clicked on, the `onclick` event handler is first executed and then (unless the handler suppresses this) the form is submitted. In practice, browsers default the `action` attribute of a `form` element to the URL of the page, so the page is reloaded in this case.

In the code, `type="button color"` is syntactically erroneous and gets ignored, so the default `type=submit` applies. The attribute specification `type="button"` is correct and makes the `button` element a “pure button” so that clicking on it has only the scripted effects, no form submission.

If you wish to style some `button` element(s) in a special way, use a `class` attribute, e.g. `<button type="button" class="color">`. The `type` attribute takes only a limited set of keywords as its values, each having a fixed meanig.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wish this would be written down in any specification... The erroneous button wasn't written be me, so it took me hours to figure out why the browser was reloading...

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons are reloading the page because they're inside a `<form>`, so it's acting as if the form is being submitted.

Add `return false;` at the end the first `onclick`.

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <button type="button color" onclick="document.getElementById('magic').innerHTML='clicked broken button'; return false;">Broken Button</button>
    <button type="button"       onclick="document.getElementById('magic').innerHTML='clicked button';"       >Button</button>
</form>
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, but i am more interested in an answer of my question :) and why is the browser not reloading after clicking on the second button?

Comment: I'm so very sorry, I totally misread your question! I honestly haven't a clue! ._.

Comment: If I had to guess, though - Because of the misformed type attribute, the browser probably processes it as the default behavior for a button, which would be to submit the form it's inside of, as where the correct attribute is passed on to the `onclick` handler.